# Telerik Kendo UI - Wizard - Dot Net Core - Partial Views & Jquery Validation

Tags: jquery, .net-core, telerik, wizard, partials

Just some piece of code to help those who want to achieve this, hope this might help:

1. Declaration of the main form without Validation DataAnnotations
2. Declaration of specific forms for each Partials to trigger Jquery Validation
3. Copy the Main ViewModel and add specific Validation DataAnnotions for the Partials

**Main Form**

```
@model MainViewModel

<form asp-action="Add" asp-controller="MyController"
      id="frmMain"
      name="frmMain"
      method="post"
      data-ajax="true"
      enctype="multipart/form-data"
      data-ajax-success="onAddMainSuccess">

    <!-- Wizard -->
    @(Html.Kendo().Wizard()
        .Name("wizard")
        .Events(ev => ev.Select("onSelect"))
        .Events(ev => ev.Done("onDone"))
        .LoadOnDemand(true)
        .ReloadOnSelect(false)
        .Steps(s =>
        {
            s.Add<MainViewModel>()
            .Title("My Partial 1")
            .ContentUrl(Url.Action("_Partial1", "MyController", Model))
            .Buttons(b =>
            {
                b.Next().Text("Suivant");
            });

            s.Add<MainViewModel>()
            .Title("My Partial 2")
            .ContentUrl(Url.Action("_Partial2", "MyController", Model))
            .Buttons(b =>
            {
                b.Next().Text("Suivant");
            });

            s.Add<MainViewModel>()
            .Title("My Partial 3")
            .ContentUrl(Url.Action("_Partial3", "MyController", Model))
            .Buttons(b =>
            {
                b.Done().Text("Enregistrer");
            });
        })
    )

</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var dataPartial1;
    var dataPartial2;
    var currentStep;

    function onSelect(e) {

        var main = $('#frmMain').serialize();
        var form, contentUrl;

        if (e.step.options.index < currentStep) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        else {

            if (e.step.options.index == 1) {
                form = $('#frmPartial1');
                dataPartial1 = form.serialize();
                contentUrl = '@Url.Action("_Partial2", "MyController")?' + main + '&' + dataPartial1;
            }
            else if (e.step.options.index == 2) {
                form = $('#frmPartial2');
                dataLesions = form.serialize();
                contentUrl = '@Url.Action("_Partial3", "MyController")?' + main + '&' + dataPartial1 + '&' + dataPartial2;
            }
 
            if (!form.valid()) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            else {
                e.step.options.contentUrl = contentUrl;
            }

        }


        currentStep = e.step.options.index;
    }

    function onNextStep(e) {
        if (e.step.options.index == 2) {
            openDoc();
        }  
    }

    function onDone(e) {

        var form = $('#frmMain');

        if (form.valid()) {
            form.submit();
        }
        
    }

    var onAddMainSuccess = function (result) {

        if (result.error) {
            alert(result.error);
        }
    };


</script>
```

**Partial (_Partial1.cshtml)**

```
@model Partial1ViewModel
<form id="frmPartial1" name="frmPartial1">
    <div class="row text-small">

        <div class="col-lg-12">
            @Html.ValidationSummary()
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Add your Fields -->
</form>

@await Html.PartialAsync("/Views/Shared/_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml")
```

**Partial1 Action Method**

```
public IActionResult _Partial1(MainViewModel mainViewModel)
{
    Partial1ViewModel model = _mapper.Map<Partial1ViewModel>(mainViewModel);

    return PartialView(model);
}
```

**Partial2 Action Method**

```
public IActionResult _Partial2(Partial1ViewModel partial1ViewModel )
{
    Partial2ViewModel model = _mapper.Map<Partial2ViewModel>(partial1ViewModel);

    return PartialView(model);
}
```

**Partial3 Action Method**

```
public IActionResult _Partial3(Partial2ViewModel partial2ViewModel )
{
    MainViewModel model = _mapper.Map<MainViewModel>(partial2ViewModel );

    return PartialView(model);
}
```